# Why I'm blocked from asking a question?

Tags: support

Last thing i did was ask a question in the logic/philosophy forum,

Only one person answered me but his way was a method i didn't learned yet, ( he answered via conditional proof, and i needed explanation/answer in the direct method) so after a day and spending on the exercises a lot of hours i was able to solve the questions by myself, and then i deleted the post since it no longer was relevant.

After that i was blocked! Why?

Comment: Have you read the linked help center thoroughly: [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: That has nothing to do with it, my questions on the logic forum weren't different then this questions for example: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/38611/how-do-you-prove-a-c-given-the-following-premises  , I'm pretty sure one of the manager blocked me for no reason, maybe it is his way for a self therapy by deciding which person he is going to block next in order to feel good with himself. Stupid site, go ahead and totally blocked me, i don't care anymore.

Comment: Yes, it has anything to do with it. Based on the [currently visible questions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/50534/dasem?tab=questions&sort=votes), you have a not-so-good history (score < 0), not to mention that deleting more questions will just worsen the situation. Also, note that the question ban is *automatically determined by the system*. No one, not even moderators can impose and release this ban (note: I'm a moderator on other SE sites).

Comment: Score is a useless criteria for anything, just because someone doesn't understand the question that doesn't mean the question isn't good. Besides by deleting a question i tought i was doing the responsible thing, especially when i aske a question that no one answering it and the single person who does answers use a method i didn't learned yet (not his fault) after finding myself solving my questions, i tought deleting it was the right thing to do. But this weird site complains about the question and simultaneously block you for  6 months for deleting it, wtf.

Comment: Maybe instead of blocking people, this weird site should delete all the posts that it thinks aren't good enough for the site? Just a smart suggestion for a stupid site. I'm done here. Bye.

Answer (score 2):

Andrew correctly posted the corresponding [help center page](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans). It is an automatic ban, no moderator or other specific person targeted you.

Now more specifically why you, personally, have been banned from asking further questions (temporarily!):

The exact algorithm is kept secret, but of your 10 questions, 4 are deleted and 5 have a negative score. As stated on the site linked above, the number of deleted questions is irrelevant. It is all about the scores. Deleting the question may have occurred at the same time, but it wasn't the reason for this ban.

Thus, instead of deleting questions, try to improve them with edits and showing your own research efforts.

Comment: What 10 questions? It shows me only 6 and a 2 deleted question (total of 8), 

And about them 

All questions were good,
The 2 that was deleted were because no one knew how to solve them and after a day and much hours i was able to solve them by myself.
And it's not temporarily the ban, it's for 6 months.

Comment: Asking about the addition rule for example is a good question in my opinion,  it is weird that this rule allows one to conclude from a car for example , the conclusion of a car or an icecream. (there is no connection between the two) and this question has been down voted, what could be the reason for that expect for illogical people that down vote the question because the aren't able to answer it or understand it.

Comment: anyway from my experience in this site, i don't remember even on case that someone was able to answer me or explain something to me to a satisfaction, eventually all my questions i had to figured them on my own ( the small cases that i accepted an answer was of courtesy to the effort or guidance of the replying person) therefore i can conclude in total that the site is more a waste of time, one can't really find or get an answer for anything in it. so the baning is probably a blessing intended  to keep from wasting time on a stupid and imposters site as a source for knowledge.

Comment: @Dasem We are a smaller site, which means that experts are on less regularly and that negative votes have more impact since they are not evened out as much as they should. On the other hand, your negatively scored questions (you cannot see the 2 that have been automatically deleted) tend to be asked in a biased way or without context. It certainly doesn't help if you continue to assume that it is everyone else's fault and has nothing to do with your style and attitude.

Comment: What biased? I was asking a question on logic with small addition of my opinion, meaning: for a logical question in theory  there is a logical answer therefore the small addition of my opinion like for example " i don't understand " or expressing that a connection should in my opinion be a necessary instead of implication etc, isn't relevant much to the correct logical answer, those expressions only emphasizes the parts that are miss understood and help understand where is the problem in general.

Comment: Maybe it because of that English isn't my native language ..? But i don't care, clearly I'm not fit to this stupid site, so i guess everyone will find their appropriate place.

Comment: @Dasem English isn't my native language as well, so what? It's **your** task to pose questions in a contextualised, intelligible way, presenting your own efforts and describing the exact problem you have. "I don't understand" or "may this have anything to do with that" are no concise **questions proper**, these are your intuitions. Yes, it is hard to convey intuitions through language, especially in a foreign one. But the proper solution is not writing a question before you are 100% sure you can, not calling others stupid.

Comment: The question of the " i don't understand " was well explained with additional 4 examples that i provided, only the title of the question i agree was not the best choice, anyway i refuse to be part of a stupid site that ban someone for something without even a warning or explanation, and as i said this site from my experience here never helped me with anything since eventually i always had to figured out the answers by myself, so it kind of useless and a wast of time site from my perspective so far. so it seems eventually that the site doesn't ban me,but rather i ban it!